# How to return value from debounced function in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js, throttling, debouncing

I have a code like that:

```
var originalFunction = function() {
    return 'some value';
};

var debouncedFunction = _.debounce(originalFunction, 3000);

console.log('debouncedFunction() result: ', debouncedFunction());

console.log('originalFunction() result: ', originalFunction());
```

[(codepen link)](http://codepen.io/dfgsfdgdsaghsdg/pen/jrrqKR?editors=0010)

And the result in the console is:

```
debouncedFunction() result:  undefined 

originalFunction() result:  some value
```

As you can see, the debounced function doesn't return anything. I understand that it's caused by an internal timer in the debounced function, but is there away around that?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

that's because debounced functions are called asynchronously - you can't return a value from them, although you can call another function passing the result:

```
var originalFunction = function() {
    console.log('some value');
    // or something like: callback(result)
};

var debouncedFunction = _.debounce(originalFunction, 3000);

console.log('debouncedFunction() result: ', debouncedFunction());
```